# Python circular import in custom package and __init__.py

Tags: python, import, package, circular-dependency

I get *ImportError: cannot import name 'Result' from partially initialized module 'libs.elastic_search_hunt' (most likely due to a circular import)* error when I try to run tests.
But I does not see any circular imports in my code.

I have a package, named **elastic_search_hunt** which contains 3 modules:

1. elastic_query.py
2. elastic_query_result.py
3. search_processor.py

And I also have **__init__.py** file with following text:

```
from libs.elastic_search_hunt.elastic_query import Query
from libs.elastic_search_hunt.search_processor import SearchProcessor
from libs.elastic_search_hunt.elastic_query_result import Result

__all__ = ['Query', 'SearchProcessor', 'Result']  # I guess it does not have any effect
```

**elastic_query.py** has only external imports.

**elastic_query_result.py** the same.

**search_processor.py** has those import:

```
from . import Query
from . import Result
```

Then I have a test file, which imports **Query** class:

```
from libs.elastic_search_hunt import Query
```

When I run tests, I get this errors:

```
test_query.py:2: in <module>
    from libs.elastic_search_hunt import Query
..\src\libs\elastic_search_hunt\__init__.py:2: in <module>
    from libs.elastic_search_hunt.search_processor import SearchProcessor
..\src\libs\elastic_search_hunt\search_processor.py:4: in <module>
    from . import Result
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'Result' from partially initialized module 'libs.elastic_search_hunt' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

But where is any circular import in my code?
I only can assume that when I import **Query** from tests, it also import **search_processor** from the **__init__.py** module which in turn loads **Query** one more time. But the error is about **Result** in **elastic_query_result** module and I see only one import of **Result**.

When i delete search_processor from **__init__.py** everything works fine.

I have read a lot of issues about circular imports, but all of them was quite obvious and does not touch the **__init__.py**. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you explain what does from * * libs.elastic_search_hunt * *  import * * Query * * do? I haven't found any documentation on this double asterisk use.

Comment: @SamuelO.D.
I am sorry, that was a typo. I've fixed it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR**: replace `from . import Query` with `from .elastic_query import Query`

**Explanation:**

When you import something from `libs.elastic_search_hunt` module it loads `__init__.py` at first. Since every module executes at first import `__init__.py` also being executed.

Then Python executes code from `__init__.py` and at second line

```
from libs.elastic_search_hunt.search_processor import SearchProcessor
```

it imports `search_processor.py`. Since it's first import - file must be executed - therefore all your imports in that file must be executed right now as well:

As you mentioned you have the following imports in your file:

```
from . import Query
from . import Result
```

At this point you tell python to load `libs.elastic_search_hunt` entire module and take `Query, Result` from it. So Python does.

It makes an attempt to load `libs/elastic_search_hunt/__init__.py` but wait... it is still not loaded completely. So it must load it, but in order to load it properly it must firstly load `search_processor` which requires `elastic_search_hunt/__init__.py` to be loaded.... oh well, there's a loop.

So in order to avoid such behaviour you should explicitly say from which module exactly you wish to load `Query` and `Result`, therefore change

```
from . import Query
from . import Result
```

to

```
from .elastic_query import Query
from .elastic_query_result import Result
```

**Example: Failed** [image: failed]
**Example: Success** [image: success]